# proving that $\frac{1}{2-e^{it}}$ is characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis

I tried to prove that $\frac{1}{2-e^{it}}$ is characteristic function by trying to compute its fourier coefficients but I did not succeed.

How to prove it? Any hint?

Comment: Looks like the Fourier transform of the law of the Geometric distribution with parameter $p=1/2$.

Comment: @romperextremeabuser excuse my brain fart.

Comment: okay seems like it is characteristic function of geometric distribution, what about $f(t)=\frac{1}{2-E(\frac{1}{1-itX})}$ where $X$ is arbitrary random variable?

I tried to construct random variable $Z$ such that it is geometrically distributed on some numbers such that when we calculate $Ee^{itZ}$ we get $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\frac{1}{2}E(\frac{1}{1-itX}))^{k}\frac{1}{2}$ but I did not succeed.

Answer (score 2):

${1 \over 2 - e^{it}} = {1 \over 2} {1 \over 1 - {e^{it} \over 2}} = { 1\over 2} (1+{e^{it} \over 2} + {e^{i2t} \over 2^2}+...) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {1 \over 2} e^{ikt} {1 \over 2} {1 \over 2^k} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {1 \over 2} e^{ikt} p (1-p)^k$, where $p={1 \over 2}$.

Hence $X$ has a geometric distribution with $p={1 \over 2}$.